# How far south can one see a rocket launch from Cape Canaveral, Florida?

Tags: launch, spacex, kennedy-space-center, cape-canaveral

I'll be in Miami this Thursday 30th of March and there is a SpaceX Falcon 9 rocket launch from LC-39A, Kennedy Space Center, Florida (if it's not delayed).

I won't be able to drive north to be on time at Cape Canaveral to see it. Is it still possible to watch the launch from anywhere along the east coast of Florida, between Miami and the launch site ? And how far north of Miami should I have to go to see something ?

I know that the best I can hope for is to see a distant light and not the actual rocket. But it's better than nothing :)

Thank you !

Comment: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/how-far-away-can-one-see-a-nasa-rocket-launch very close to being a duplicate.

Comment: I found this question, but it's for a different launch location.

Comment: The range should be similar

Comment: I don't know, it's not the same rocket, neither the same launch direction... I believe it goes more north-east than south-east from launch site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.

I don't want to link the picture here directly because of license you can see what a STS (Space Shuttle) launch looks like from Miami:

http://chicagoboyz.net/archives/6433.html

Yes, the rockets are different, yes the trajectory is different (No it does not go north east as you said, but south east towards the equator), but this is not enough to make a difference for you.

The previous question linked shows that antares launches can be seen as far as 700km away. You will be 350 km away.

The only reason why you would not be able to see it is if the weather is cloudy.

Answer (score 6):

I can see them from the opposite side of Florida with the naked eye given correct atmospheric conditions. So it is possible to have a LoS of about the entire state of Florida, probably further if you are in an open area.

Comment: This is potentially an answer, but currently it is not complete. Can you please expand it?

Comment: @Hohmannfan sounds complete to me

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to.  Considering that I can see every launch from Palm Beach Cty. clearly, you slould be able to.  You said you will be Miami so I reccomend viewing from a beach or where you have an unobstructed view north.  I also reccomend a good pair of binoculars.

Comment: That's 244km by road from Canaveral.

Answer (score 4):

I just watched a SpaceX launch from Tampa Florida.  Used Google Earth to determine the heading to look.  Cool clear day and was able to see it just fine.  Binoculars helped, but could see it without.

Comment: how far away is that?

Comment: Tampa is almost 200km from Canaveral.

Answer (score 3):

I saw the initial Falcon Heavy launch from Juno Beach, Florida and have seen other launches including the Space Shuttle from various locations in Palm Beach County

Answer (score 2):

I saw a rocket launch from mississippi once. It just looked like a really bright light in the sky that started to arc over and then shot off, well like a rocket. Lol

Answer (score 2):

[image]

View from the 8th Floor of the
Mayo Building in Jacksonville  FL

Good viewing spot for the up coming
Falcon Heavy Launch tomorrow
or Wednesday !!