# Would the Saturday May 30th 2020 SpaceX launch visible from Boca Raton?

Tags: spacex, launch, nasa, visibility-of-spacecraft

Will I be able to see the SpaceX Crew Demo-2 launch this Saturday May 30th if I’m at the beach in Boca Raton, Florida and the launch takes place?

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20849/

Comment: Were you successful? Had they left your question open a little longer you could have posted a first-hand account as an answer and picked up some reputation