# From where will the planned Artemis I launch be visible?

Tags: sls, observation, artemis-program, launch-trajectories, kennedy-space-center

The [latest planned Artemis I launch window](https://blogs.nasa.gov/artemis/2022/10/12/nasa-sets-date-for-next-launch-attempt-for-artemis-i-moon-mission/) is 69 minutes long, opening 2022-11-14T00:07:00−05:00, which if used will lead to a launch in complete darkness. I'm interested in the possibility of observing the launch from a relatively long distance away. To work out if anything will be visible to an observer we need to know:

- If there will be a line of sight from the observer to the SLS

  - Any bounds there are on the trajectory the launch will follow will thus be useful
- How bright the SLS exhaust will be, and whether this changes along its trajectory

  - From this we can make some estimate of whether an observer with direct line of sight is near enough to see it by naked eye or with some magnification

My personal interest in this is the possibility of observing the launch from on board a flight that departs Nassau (some 490km from the KSC) shortly before the launch window opens. This seems to be in the realms of possibility given by [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20850/23692) but I don't know how much difference the engineering of the SLS compared to the STS or launching for lunar orbit rather than earth orbit might make to the trajectory and/or brightness of the upcoming launch. Any details that contribute to predicting the visibility from any location would be welcome.

Comment: possibly helpful: [How can Flightclub.io Camera Tools be used to simulate launch photography geometry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26686/12102) I see that flightclub.io already has an Artemis 1 template

Comment: @uhoh THANK YOU, I was wracking my brain trying to remember Flightclub and Google was not helping.

Comment: @ErinAnne the first rule of Flightclub...